# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'file'

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm new to AsP.net when i'm trying my usual code to connect to database there's exception keep shown and idon't know what's wrong
the exception is :

```
" System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'file'."
```

and this my code :

```
string ID = Request.QueryString["id"];

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select title,file path,Upload Date from [Media] where ID=@id", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SqlDataReader rdr=null;

try
{
    conn.Open();
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // print the CustomerID of each record
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            pathTextBox.Text = rdr["file Path"].ToString();
            DateTextBox.Text = rdr["Upload Date"].ToString();
            titleTextBox.Text = rdr["title"].ToString();
        }

        Image1.ImageUrl = pathTextBox.Text;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please show your `SqlCommand`.

Comment: I think column names should not contains spaces

Answer (score 1):

If your column names contains white space (which is not recomended) you should use square brackets like `[]`. For example, `[Upload Date]`

Column names must follow the rules for identifiers.

From [`Database Identifiers`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM [My Table]      --Identifier contains a space and uses a reserved keyword.
WHERE [order] = 10   --Identifier is a reserved keyword.
```

That's why you should use them like;

```
select title,[file path],[Upload Date]
```

Also you don't add your parameter value anywhere in your code.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select title,[file path],[Upload Date] from Media where ID=@id", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", YourIDValue);
```

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString))
{
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
   {
      //Your code..
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have spaces in column names you need to use brackets like below

`select title,[file path],[Upload Date] from [Media] where ID=@id`

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(SomeConnectionString))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "select title,[file path],[Upload Date] from [Media] where ID=@id";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idval); // set the id parameter
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read()) // you don't need while loop
        {
            pathTextBox.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("[file path]"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot it works now ..... can any one help me to display an image with path that i read from data base in image viewer in ASP